# Display input from user, using toString() Method

Tags: java

I'm trying to finish this homework:

Create a simple Friendsclass with, as a minimum, the following:

- name and age fields
- appropriate constructors
- get/set methods
- toString() method

Create an ArrayList of Friends

Run the program from a menu with the following options:

- Add a Friend
- Remove a Friend
- Display all Friends
- Exit

And this is what I got so far:

Friends.class

```
    public class Friends 
    {
       public static String name;
       public static int age;

       // parameters
       public Friends(String name, int age)
       {
          this.name = name;
          this.age = age;
       }

       // set name
       public static void setName(String friendName)
       {
          name = friendName;
       }

       // get name
       public static String getName()
       {
          return name;
       }

       // set age
       public static void setAge(int friendAge)
       {
          age = friendAge;
       }

       // get age
       public static int getAge()
       {
          return age;
       }

       // return toString()
       public String toString()
       {
       return this.getName() + " " + this.getAge();
       }

    } //end clas
```

And FriendsTest.class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FriendsTest
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

      // objects
      ArrayList<Friends> friendsList = new ArrayList<>();

      Friends a1 = new Friends("James", 10);
      Friends a2 = new Friends("Christopher", 17);
      Friends a3 = new Friends("George", 25);
      Friends a4 = new Friends("Linda", 31);
      Friends a5 = new Friends("Karen", 62);

      friendsList.add(a1);
      friendsList.add(a2);
      friendsList.add(a3);
      friendsList.add(a4);
      friendsList.add(a5);

      // menu

      int menu_choice;

      do
      {
         System.out.println("\n1. Add a Friend");
         System.out.println("2. Remove a Friend");
         System.out.println("3. Display all Friends");
         System.out.println("4. Exit");

         System.out.print("\nSelect one option: ");
         menu_choice = input.nextInt();

         switch (menu_choice)
         {
            case 1:
               System.out.print("Enter Friend's name: ");
               Friends.setName(input.next());

               System.out.print("Enter Friend's age: ");
               Friends.setAge(input.nextInt());

               Friends a6 = new Friends(Friends.getName(), Friends.getAge());
               friendsList.add(a6);
               break;

            case 2:
               System.out.println("Enter Friend's name to remove: ");
               Friends.setName(input.next());

               friendsList.remove(Friends.getName());
               break;

            case 3:
               for(int k = 0; k < friendsList.size(); k++)
               {
                  System.out.println(friendsList.get(k).name + " " + friendsList.get(k).age);
               }
               break;

            case 4:
               System.exit(0);

         }//end switch        



      } while (menu_choice != 4);


   }//end main



}//end class
```

When I run the program, neither Option 1, 2 and 3 seems to work:

With (1) I get the user input 5 times...
With (2) I get the the input 5 times too
If I select display(3) I get: "Karen 62" 5 times...

I'm not sure if I applying the loop correctly and if I'm using the setters and getters correctly.

Comment: Why just write `static` when it clearly isn't needed? Use an IDE; it will tell you exactly what's wrong with you using `this.name` when `name` isn't a variable of `this` (though this is still valid syntax for some reason). It will also refactor a ton of code for you. Never write a program without an IDE...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to recommend you to use an IDE (for example ECLIPSE[it's free]). An IDE is an integrated development environment, which is basically a text editor(like word or notepad) that would help you minimize errors (mostly syntax errors) in your code.

Things you should fix in your code:

1. In the **Friends** class you should erase all of the 'static' keywords. Plus, I would recommend you to use **private** instead of **public** all of the attributes of this class (that means in **name** and in **age** you should use **private** instead of **public**).
2. In the **FriendsTest** class:

case 1:

```
System.out.println("Enter Friend's name: ");
String name = input.next();

System.out.println("Enters Friend's age: ");
int age = input.next();

Friends a6  = new Friends(name,age);
friendsList.add(a6);
break;
```

case 2:

You need to learn how to use an **iterator** (look it up at java's API) if you are working with an ArrayList.
The **remove**(int index) method only lets you delete an object in a specified postion (that means you should know the postion of the friend you want to delete in the friendsList).

case 3:

You should use an **iterator** to iterate in the friendsList and use the **toString** method of the **Friends** class to print each friend.

Answer (score 0):

You should not declare the `Friends` class's properties as **static**, neither its **getters** & **setters** :

Change

```
public static String name;
public static int age;

public static void setName(String friendName) ...
public static String getName() ...
public static void setAge(int friendAge) ...
public static int getAge() ...
```

to

```
public String name;
public int age;

public void setName(String friendName) ...
public String getName() ...
public void setAge(int friendAge) ...
public int getAge() ...
```

**main() :**

```
 switch (menu_choice)
 {
     case 1:
          String name;
          int age;
          System.out.print("Enter Friend's name: ");
          name = input.next();

          System.out.print("Enter Friend's age: ");
          age = input.nextInt();

          Friends a6 = new Friends(name, age);

          friendsList.add(a6);
          break;
        . ...
```

Retrieve the `name` & `age` separatly, create a new `Friends` object with the corresponding `name` & `age`, the add it to the `ArrayList`. (Adjust this with the other cases accordingly)